# Multiple arguments with cmd.exe via a C# Process

Tags: c#, process, cmd, esri

I try to call the esriRegAsm.exe with arguments from a C# program.
The purpose is to register a Dll. Therefore I usually call the esriRegAsm.exe with the Dll as argument plus some additional parameters (/p:Desktop /s). This works fine if I type it into cmd.exe. Somehow I think that the process sends only the first string to the cmd and not the whole argument list, but I need the "" for the space character in the paths.
For debugging I added a message box and the strings seems to be okay.

Backslash or double backslash seems to be unimportant.

```
        string targetDir = this.Context.Parameters["targ"];
        string programFilesFolder = this.Context.Parameters["proFiles"];

        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "/C \"" + programFilesFolder + "Common Files\\\\ArcGIS\\\\bin\\\\esriRegAsm.exe\" " + "\"" + targetDir + "RArcGISTest.dll\"  /p:Desktop /s";
        MessageBox.Show("/C \"" + programFilesFolder + "Common Files\\\\ArcGIS\\\\bin\\\\esriRegAsm.exe\" " + "\"" + targetDir + "RArcGISTest.dll\"  /p:Desktop /s");
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
```

As I cannot attache a picture of the message box... the output is:

/C "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ArcGIS\bin\esriRegAsm.exe" "C:\install\RArcGISTest.dll" /p:Desktop /s"

Comment: And the question is ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you double-escaping things, and why are you routing it through `cmd.exe`? Just execute the process directly:

```
string targetDir = this.Context.Parameters["targ"];
string programFilesFolder = this.Context.Parameters["proFiles"];

Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(programFilesFolder, @"Common Files\ArcGIS\bin\esriRegAsm.exe");
startInfo.Arguments = "\"" + Path.Combine(targetDir, "RArcGISTest.dll") + "\" /p:Desktop /s";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Comment: works for me :) thank you... I double escaped it because I saw something similar for the targetDir string. And yes, it its stupid to use the command line.